Load main domain from a directory for a Laravel project
I have a domain example.com, as well as some sub-domains sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, ..etc. I want to load the main domain from a directory to organize the directories to avoid having Laravel project files and folders next to sub-domains folders.
public_html structure:
main
    app
    bootstrap
    ..
    public
    ..
sub1
    //Some files and directories
sub2
    //Some files and directories
.htaccess

.htaccess:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/public/$1 [L]

This code will load files for example.com from example.com/main/public.
The issue is that when I leave the website opened in a browser tab for a while (maybe a couple of hours) and visit that tab, the URL becomes example.com/main/public. If I type example.com/main/public in the browser the website loads as well.
Is there a way to force it to load the website from example.com only?

The question is unclear. (wondering how this was passed the Staging Ground). This code will load files for example.com from example.com/main/public Okay URL becomes example.com/main/public It should because same page(Unless you have inactive catchers ). If I type example.com/main/public in the browser the website loads as well. ???

@AbdullaNilam I don't want the URL to contain main/public. The website should be loaded from example.com only.
